# Why does mySQL concat fail on a different platform?

Tags: php, mysql

PHP is returning the error:

```
"FUNCTION archemar_1.concat does not exist"
```

The only place in my php file where I call the concat function is here, if indeed that is the problem.

```
$full_name = database::query("SELECT concat (fname, ' ', lname) from cr WHERE email='$email'");
```

This function runs fine on my local xampp server but not when I upload it to my production server.  This makes me think it is a platform issue perhpas with having to do with the PHP or mySQL version and the syntax I'm using.  If any more info. is needed I can post it.

Thanks.

Comment: you may also want to add `AS` so you can reference it easier `concat(fname, ' ', lname) AS fullname`

Comment: fname and lname are mysql column names.  So how do I reference it later?  Sounds good though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without the space between the function name and the parenthesis:

```
$full_name = database::query("SELECT concat(fname, ' ', lname) from cr WHERE email='$email'");
```

See http://datacharmer.blogspot.com/2005/12/function-wellknownfunc-does-not-exist.html for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space between `CONCAT` and the open parenthesis.  This is a place where MySQL is picky -- if you have a space between the function name and the open parenthesis then it is attempting to resolve it as a user-defined functions.  Built-in functions do not use a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $full_name = database::query("SELECT concat_ws(' ', fname, lname) AS fullname
                               FROM cr 
                               WHERE email='$email'");
 $fullname['fullname'];
```